# How to include Session Timeout in all controllers?

Tags: php, session-timeout

I need a session timeout for my website.

My current code works when I add it in all functions on all my controllers.

Is there a way to write it only once and include it to all of the controllers?

-in config file with URL & Session check or so?

My code which works:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['timeout']) && $_SESSION['timeout'] + 4 < time()) //4 seconds
{
 session_destroy();
 echo "<script>
 alert('Session Timed Out.');
 </script>";
 ?>  <script> window.location ="<?php echo URL;?>"; </script>  <?php
}
$_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
```

The above code works when I add this in all functions on all my controllers.
But I need a single page code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start the session before you could destroy it

use the following code in your config file

```
        session_start();
        if(isset($_SESSION['timeout']) && $_SESSION['timeout'] + 4 < time()) //4 seconds
        {
            session_destroy();
            echo "<script>
         alert('Session Timed Out.');
         </script>";
            ?>  <script> window.location ="<?php echo URL;?>"; </script>  <?php
        }
        $_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
```

and delete session_start from your controller files. It should work, I tested it on my localhost

Edit

To exclude login page use the following code
assuming that your login page url contains "login", modify $string as per your login page url

```
        $string = "login";
        $url =  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

        session_start();
        if(isset($_SESSION['timeout']) && $_SESSION['timeout'] + 4 < time() && !strpos($url, $string)) //4 seconds
        {
            session_destroy();
            echo "<script>
                 alert('Session Timed Out.');
                 </script>";
            ?>  <script> window.location ="<?php echo URL;?>"; </script>  <?php
                }
                $_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
```

Comment: how to exclude my login page from this condition?

Comment: welcome :), feel free to post here if you face any other difficulty

Answer (score 0):

place this code in common or config php file

```
<?php
  if ($_SESSION['timeout'] + 10 * 60 < time()) {
       // session timed out
 } else {
      // session ok
  }
?>
```

Comment: I tried this Arun. This code works only if I add it in all functions of all my controllers. This is not working in config.

Comment: as mentioned simple MVC

Comment: Okay.. place your coding in public function __construct() { // place your code// }

Answer (score 0):

You can set session parameters with

**session_set_cookie_params** http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php